# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when trying to configure MongoDB with my spring boot application:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource

```
Code is as below

    package com.women.code.application;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class WomenInCodeApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args){
           SpringApplication.run(WomenInCodeApplication.class, args);
       }
    }


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/USER/WomenInComputing/")
    public class WomenInCodeMgmtController {

        @Autowired
        private QueryDb queryDb; 

        @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public UserRequest add(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {

            return queryDb.saveToRepository();
        }
    }

@Component
public class QueryDb implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public UserRequest saveToRepository(){
        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
        userRequest.setFirstName("Isaac");
        userRequest.setLastName("Lavoie");
        return repository.save(userRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserRequest> save(Iterable<? extends UserRequest> entites) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserRequest> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserRequest> findAll(Sort sort) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<UserRequest> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserRequest save(UserRequest entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserRequest findOne(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Long count() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(UserRequest entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends UserRequest> entities) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public UserRequest findByFirstName(String firstName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserRequest> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

    public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<UserRequest, String> {

        public UserRequest findByFirstName(String firstName);
        public List<UserRequest> findByLastName(String lastName);
        public UserRequest saveToRepository();
    }

public class UserRequest {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }



    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserRequest [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", username=" + username
                + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WomenForCode</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- <start-class>com.women.code.controller.WomenInCodeMgmtController</start-class> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add the dependencies that you're using to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram Added the pom.xml

Comment: You can try using `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>` and get rid of data commons and mongo driver as this will transitively download the correct compatible version.